# SSL version set up in JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

How to set  SSL version in JMeter

Iam looking for an JMeter equivalent to the Loadrunner step -
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS1.2");

I get the below issue

Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 1):

As per [Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https) article for [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) [default TLS protocol is TLS1.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default) so you don't have to do anything.

If your JDK is using different default protocol you can override it by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [JMeter Bug 58236](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58236)

---

However your problem: `Connection timed out: connect` doesn't have anything in common with HTTPS version, it indicates that JMeter failed to establish the connection with the server within the default timeout time frame, you need to look into the connectivity issues, for example it might be the case you need to [configure the proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)